# How to unprotect an Excel workbook

Tags: vba, excel, password-protection

I have an Excel workbook that is password protected (the entire document, not just a sheet or set of sheets - you can't open the file without the password).  I know the password, so I am able to open it, but there is no obvious way to turn off the password protection.

Specifically, I would like to do this in VBA, because eventually I want to be able to do this to multiple files using a loop.  I tried using:

```
ThisWorkbook.Unprotect(Password = "[password]")
```

but this does absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's the password to open the file, you want:

```
Thisworkbook.Password = ""
```

then save it.

`Wb.Unprotect` would remove the password that protects the workbook structure/windows.

Answer (score 3):

[Here is what the MSDN says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196695.aspx)

```
Sub Example()
    Dim WB as Workbook
    Dim pw as String

    Set WB = ThisWorkbook
    pw = "Your password"
    WB.Unprotect(pw)
End Sub
```