# Unprotect workbook using VbScript

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I'm using Vbscript to copy worksheets from one workbook to another workbook. I've protected the workbook to prevent anyone from deleting sheets. Because of workbook protection, vbscript cannot copy sheets. I don't know how to unprotect the workbook using vbscript. Does anyone have idea?

Comment: `Workbook.Unprotect [password]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to unprotect an Excel workbook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31297188/how-to-unprotect-an-excel-workbook)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
Workbooks.Unprotect Password

your code here

Workbooks.Protect Password
```